# nginx error log file not found

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have the following lines in my nginx.conf file :

```
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
```

This clearly indicates the location of error log file. I am seeing a nginx error on my website but I am unable to find the file on this location. The folder nginx is empty.

Comment: What is the `nginx` error you see on your website?

Comment: It just says there is an error and says we can modify the page from this location but doesn't describe what the error is.